# NullPointerException in ActiveMQ with JDBC storage

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, transactions, activemq-classic

When activemq 5.14.5 is configured with a JDBC persistence storage (Postgresql 9.5, DBCP2 pool) from time to time an error appears:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.prepare(JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.java:75)
                at org.apache.activemq.transaction.XATransaction.prepare(XATransaction.java:188)
                at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransactionBroker.prepareTransaction(TransactionBroker.java:247)
                at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.prepareTransaction(MutableBrokerFilter.java:133)
                at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.prepareTransaction(MutableBrokerFilter.java:133)
                at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processPrepareTransaction(TransportConnection.java:519)
                at org.apache.activemq.command.TransactionInfo.visit(TransactionInfo.java:98)
                at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:336)
                at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:200)
                at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
                at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:125)
                at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:301)
                at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
                at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)[47:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.5]
                at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[47:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.14.5]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_131]
```

It appears when ActiveMQ is involved in XA transaction:

```
XID:[1197822575,globalId=2c162f175c1006f72672e6170616368652e61726965732e7472616e73616374696f6e0000000000000000000000000000,branchId=2000ffffffe5ffffff8319175c1006170616368652e61726965732e7472616e73616374696f6e0000000000000000000000000000] failed with: javax.jms.JMSException: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.jms.JMSException: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
                at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1399)
                at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1428)
                at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.prepare(TransactionContext.java:469)
                at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.WrapperNamedXAResource.prepare(WrapperNamedXAResource.java:86)
                at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.internalPrepare(TransactionImpl.java:429)
                at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:312)
                at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
                at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1020)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
                at org.apache.aries.transaction.internal.AriesPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AriesPlatformTransactionManager.java:75)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:484)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)[90:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:4.2.8.RELEASE_1]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
                at ...... // custom service
```

It seams like some concurrency issue in ActiveMQ [JdbcMemoryTransactionStore](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/activemq-5.14.5/activemq-jdbc-store/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/store/jdbc/JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.java) when iterating over collection:

```
    for (Iterator<AddMessageCommand> iter = tx.messages.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        AddMessageCommand cmd = iter.next();
        cmd.run(ctx); // here is NPE (line 75)
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the object `ctx` from? Your code doesn't seem to be showing from where, update your question with full code!

Comment: It is for sure that you are passing `null` as `ctx` object!

Comment: The code that throws NPE is internal code of ActiveMQ (server): https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/activemq-5.14.5/activemq-jdbc-store/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/store/jdbc/JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.java. It's not a problem with `ctx` but `cmd`.